# Insert data into SAP HANA via JDBC on Android

Tags: android, jdbc, hana

I am trying to insert data from an Android phone via JDBC into a SAP HANA instance (no HCP, it is a physical one). I am developing the Android app via AndroidStudio. I am totally new to Android app development and SAP HANA.

I found out that I need to import ngdbc.jar driver somehow into my project. I imported the file from my HANA studio into my AndroidStudio project by adding the .jar module to my project.

When I try to run the app I get following error message:

```
08-20 15:34:17.306  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver
08-20 15:34:17.329  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-20 15:34:17.329  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
08-20 15:34:17.329  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:272)
08-20 15:34:17.329  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at com.iot.fb.sensor.MainActivity.insert(MainActivity.java:84)
08-20 15:34:17.329  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at com.iot.fb.sensor.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:68)
08-20 15:34:17.329  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-20 15:34:17.329  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.iot.fb.sensor-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-20 15:34:17.329  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-20 15:34:17.330  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-20 15:34:17.330  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
08-20 15:34:17.330  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ ... 6 more
08-20 15:34:17.330  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver
08-20 15:34:17.330  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-20 15:34:17.330  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
08-20 15:34:17.330  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
08-20 15:34:17.330  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
08-20 15:34:17.330  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ ... 7 more
08-20 15:34:17.330  21714-22168/com.iot.fb.sensor W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
08-20 15:34:30.762  21714-21727/com.iot.fb.sensor W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 21.900ms
```

I assigned a button the `startConnect()` method to create a thread running the `insert()` method.

```
   public void startConnect(View v) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                insert();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

In the `insert()` method, I am loading the driver, establishing the connection and inserting my data:

```
protected void insert(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
            java.sql.Connection c = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sap://xxx.com:3xx15/HDB", "myUser", "myPassword");
            PreparedStatement st = c.prepareStatement("insert into \"MY_SCHEMA\".\"MY_TABLE\" values (?,?,?)");
            int time = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis());
            Timestamp tsTemp = new Timestamp(time);
            st.setTimestamp(1, tsTemp);//TIMESTAMP YYYY-MM-DD HH:SS.FF3
            st.setFloat(2, 33);//VALUE_A
            st.setInt(3, 99);//VALUE_B
            st.executeUpdate();
            st.close();
            c.close();


        }
        catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What I would like to know is:

- How can I fix the driver issue?
- Besides the driver issue, is my code correct regarding **port**, my **insert** into schema and table syntax, and the URL ending with **HDB** (I stumbled over it somewhere)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The URL is not correct, no. 
Please check [HANA JDBC docu](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/ff/15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4/content.htm) for questions like that.

The error message

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class  com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.iot.fb.sensor-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

seems to indicate that the JDBC driver .jar was not even looked at when searching for the JDBC driver class. Are you sure that you correctly imported it and included it to the classpath?

Comment: Thank you Lars for your reply. I am not sure if I imported the driver correctly. I tried two things. I first added the ngdbc.jar to the project's libs folder and clicked "add to library". This did not solve the problem. Then I imported the ngdbc.jar as a .jar module. I also checked if the modul dependency existed to that module under Module Settings -> Modules "app" -> Dependencies. I did exist. That was my understanding of "2. Add ngdbc.jar to your classpath.". Maybe I am wrong. How can I correctly add this ngdbc.jar to my classpath?

Comment: Sorry, no idea on Android development. I wouldn't even know whether the JDK is fully standard compliant or not. Maybe certain parts of the API have not been ported? - sorry, that's all guessing!

Comment: I am not sure about android but I also faced this in my web app when i added a jar then I had to Install the JAR into my local Maven repository and worked.Is there anything like this in android?